# Separating an input file into two different 2d Arrays

Tags: c, arrays

I'm currently working on an assignment that requires me to take an input file, separate it and store the contents into two different arrays.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>



int main()
{
        char DataMem[32][3];
        int RegMem[32][10];
        char line[100][21]; //Holds the value for each line in the input file
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;


        while(fgets(line[i], 20, stdin) != NULL)
        {
                line[i++];
                if(line[i] == " ")
                        DataMem[j] = line[i];
                //printf("%s", line[3]);
        }



return 0;
}
```

Suppose the input file looks something like:

```
95864312
68957425
-136985475
36547566
24957986
1

45
98
```

where the first values before the 1, are stored into the array named line, and the lines following the blank line need to be put into the array DataMem.

Can anyone point me into the direction as to how to do this? I can fill in the array line correctly, however I am having a hard time stopping the fill at that point and subsequently filling the rest of the file into the array datamem.

Thank you

Comment: The statement `line[i++];` does nothing except increase `i` by one. Which means that the next use of `line[i]` will be using *an uninitialized string*. Besides, you can't compare strings using `==`, as it will compare *pointers*. You also can't assign arrays, only copy them. I suggest you find and get a couple of books to read, from the very beginning.

Comment: @^ This is a programming forum site, where people ask programming questions, whether simple or not, to get thoughtful answers. To respond to such a question by suggesting to leave the site and find a different source of information, unless you link to a particularly helpful resource elsewhere, is to defeat the purpose of the site. I do recommend the rest of your comment to be read though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several issues; one is that (as Some programmer dude says) is that you do i++ so your test of line[i] == " " references uninitialized memory.

You also have a problem in that you cannot compare strings using ==, you must use strcmp().  The issue is that strings in C are actually pointers, so

```
char *foo = "Hello";
char *bar = "Hello";
if (foo == bar)
    printf("This will never print out\n")
```

is not going to do what you expect--you will never see the printout, as the way this will (likely) compile is that foo will be set to point to an address in memory (say 0x1000) that has 'H' in 0x1000, 'e' in 0x1001, etc, up to 'o' in 0x1004, and '\0' in 0x1005.  The bar variable will point to some other address (say 0x2000) which will hold the string "Hello" also.  So while both strings are the same, the if test is actually testing `if (0x1000 == 0x2000)`, which will fail--you need to do `if (!strcmp(foo, bar))` to actually test the contents.

[Note: this example is actually flawed in that most modern compilers will simply create one instance of the "Hello" string in read-only memory and point both variables at it, so the if test would actually work in this case.  But you shouldn't rely on that and it definitely does not hold for the general case.]

Your test on line[i] looks wrong also, as I suspect you want to copy strings that start with a space, not strings that are exactly " ", so I suspect you actually want to test on line[i][0].  But I can't be sure without knowing your assignment.

Your declaration of DataMem is incorrect also--you have declared it as 32 3-char entries, but you are writing line[i] into it and line[i] is a pointer.  You either need to declare all instances big enough to hold the entire string you want (presumably the same 21 bytes that line can hold) and copy into it, or you need to declare it as an array of pointers (`char *DataMem[32]`).  There is a key difference you need to understand: if you copy the string, then if you modify DataMem's view of the string, line's view of the string is unchanged.  If you simply copy the pointer then changing one string changes both (because they are both pointing at exactly the same memory).  Obviously, copying the string is slower and takes more memory (well, except for very short strings).

The magic numbers are bad as well.  Instead of 20 and 21, for example, I would do `#define MAX_STRING_LEN 20` and use it in the code.  (Good job remembering to declare the array big enough to hold the terminating NIL by the way.  However fgets() already is aware of the need and will read in up to one fewer characters so there is room for the NIL.  You should be passing in 21 not 20).  Also, I would pass sizeof(line[i]) as the argument to fgets(), not MAX_STRING_LEN (and certainly not 20).  That way if the size of line[i] ever changes the code will still be correct; if you pass in the same dimension that you used to declare the variable someone might change it without realizing they need to change it here too.

Finally, you need to bounds-check inside your loop.  What happens if the input is longer than the 100 entries you declared for line[]?  Without a test you run the risk of writing beyond your variable boundary (which tends to lead to really hard-to-find bugs).  A very useful macro is

```
#define NELEM(x)    (sizeof(x) / sizeof(*(x)))
```

which you could use to do the test:

```
if (i >= NELEM(line)) {
    printf("Data overflow\n");
    exit(1);
}
```

so you don't need to embed the 100 (or the #define you replace it with) inside your code.  (The #define works by taking the size of the entire data structure and dividing it by the size of the first element in it.  And all the parentheses are actually required).

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char DataMem[32][3];
    char line[100][21]; //Holds the value for each line in the input file

    for(int i = 0; fgets(line[i], 20, stdin) != NULL ; ++i)
    { 
        if('\r' == line[i][0] || '\n' == line[i][0]) {
            break;
        }

        printf("line[%d] = %s",i, line[i]);
    }

    for(int i = 0; fgets(DataMem[i], 20, stdin) != NULL ; ++i)
    {
        printf("DataMem[%d] = %s",i, DataMem[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```